# How to pass data to template automatically in Go?

Tags: go

Right now i am using [Gorilla context](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/context) package to pass data around in my middlewares & controllers, but what i want to do is pass the data directly to my [Pongo2](https://github.com/flosch/pongo2) template so later in my controller i don't have to get the data from the Gorilla context and manually pass it to the template context, for those of you familiar with express.js it would be like

```
var user = {
    name: "Name",
    age: 0
}

response.locals = user
```

Edit: So every pongo2 template needs access to a User object, right now i fetch the user from database using middleware and using Gorilla context pass the data to my controller, from there on to my template on each controller but what i want to do is pass the User object to template from my middleware instead of using Gorilla context.

```
func UserMiddleware(next http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

       user := &User{} // user will normally be fetched from database
       context.Set(req, "user", user)
       next.ServeHTTP(res, req)
    })
}
```

Then In My Request Handler

```
func Handler(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    tpl, _ := pongo2.FromFile("view/template.html")
    user := context.Get(req, "user").(*User)
    data := pongo2.Context{
       "user": user,
    }
    out, _ := tpl.Execute(data)
    res.Write([]byte(out))
}
```

For all of my handlers i have to pass in user to template like that, but i want to pass it in from my middleware so that i don't have to do it in each of my handlers.

Comment: you are using two package Gorilla and Pongo, of course you need write some code to glue them together. or please make the question more specific

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Having to pull the User from the context and pass it to the template isn't odd — that's 4 lines of code in the handler? There really isn't a way to 'simplify' this.

Comment: it makes a difference when there are potentially 100s of request handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

invoke `MyExecute(req, tpl)` instead of `tpl.Execute(data)`

```
func MyExecute(req *http.Request, tpl TemplateSet) (string, error){
    gorillaObj := context.GetAll(req)
    pongoObj := make(map[string]interface{})

    for key, value := range gorillaObj {
        if str, ok := key.(string); ok{
            pongoObj[str] = value
        }
    }

    return tpl.Execute(pongo2.Context(pongoObj))
}
```

not tested, it should work.
the most problem is that gorilla use `map[interface{}]interface{}` as store, but pongo use `map[string]interface{}`, note not to use non-string as key in gorilla context.

Comment: Tried it but pongo2.Context doesn't support indexing, it does have an update method that takes another pongo2.Context though, i don't know what i can do with that

Comment: Great but because `context.GetAll()` returns `map[interface{}]interface{}`, it needs type assertion before the key can be converted to string, problem is, when i try to assert it, it panics saying **interface conversion: interface is mux.contextKey, not string**

Comment: @JiangYD Should that be `if str, ok := key.(string); ok {` ?